# merge sorted list<int>

Tags: c#, sorting

I have two already sorted `List<int>`, how do I efficiently merge them into just one sorted list?

For example:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = new List<int>() {1, 4, 5};
List<int> aAndB = ....?
```

I would like that my `aAndB` list ot look like: `{1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: Beware of answers which require you to re-sort the lists. ;)

Comment: @HimBromBeere, totally agree with you. I saw a similar question last week as well, so OP should have done a little research before asking such trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Concat` or `AddRange` to merge two lists like this:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
List<int> b = new List<int>() {1, 4, 5};

//using Concat
List<int> aAndB = a.Concat(b).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

//using AddRange
aAndB = new List<int>(a).AddRange(b).Sort();
```

Comment: `Union` will remove the duplicates.

Comment: indeed, did not read the question properly

Comment: `AddRange` doesn't return a list or anything, so you can't chain `OrderBy`

Comment: `AddRange` also modifies the collection `a`.

Comment: ok .. another question. using orderby i'm just resorting the list again or not?

Comment: Yes, you're resorting the list again,

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Concat` and `Order` these lists like:

```
List<int> aAndB = a.Concat(b).OrderBy(r=> r).ToList();
```

Another way to do the same with `List<T>` would be to use `AddRange` and `Sort` methods available on `List<T>` like:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5 };
List<int> aAndB = new List<int>(a);
aAndB.AddRange(b);
aAndB.Sort();
```

Comment: You're creating a new list `a` and then adding range from list `a`, you should be using list `b` :-)

Comment: @Peroxy, not really sure if the op wanted to keep the original lists intact or not

Comment: you did not read my comment correctly. You create a list `aAndB`, which is equal to list `a`. Then you add range `a` again, when you should be adding range of list `b`. Should be `aAndB.AddRange(b)` instead of your `aAndB.AddRange(a)`.

Comment: @Peroxy, lol, you are absolutely right, modified my answer, thanks for pointing it out.